# Protractor: TypeError: config.suite.split is not a function, protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:155

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, q

I'm working with protractor version **5.1.1** , but when I try to run it, it gives me following error

```
D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:155
            throw e;
            ^

TypeError: config.suite.split is not a function
at Function.getSpecs (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:76:26)
at new TaskScheduler (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\protractor\built\taskScheduler.js:33:100)
at helper.runFilenameOrFn_.then.then.then (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:174:25)
at _fulfilled (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
at runSingle (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
at flush (D:\tools\protractor\5.1.1\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
```

I've googled it but couldn't find any solution for my particular problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Protractor version: **5.1.1**
npm version: **3.8.6**
node version: **6.11.0**

Comment: Your input on which you want to use `split` is not made for this command. Are your suites an array of strings?

Comment: Ignore the promises. The relevant line is `configParser.js:76:26`.

Comment: Please upload your protractor conf file